# How to design a feedback form using SharePoint online modern pages without using microsoft forms

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience, microsoft-forms

I need to create a SharePoint modern page in which our clients can give us feedback (rate us and perhaps let us some suggestions).

We are not allowed to use microsoft forms. What other possibilities do I have?

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a [SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) web part for your requirements.

Check below SPFx sample which will help you to get started. You can download it & use it as is or enhance the functionality as per your requirements:

[SPFx React Feedback web part](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-feedback)